# Applying L’hôpital’s rule to an exponential function yielding different results

Tags: probability

I was solving problem 2.38b in Casella and Berger when I came across the below issue:

$$\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} f_{P}(p) = p^{r}.[1 - (1 - p)e^{2tp}]^{-r}$$

Applying L’hôpital’s rule to:

$$\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \frac{p^{r}}{[1 - (1 - p)e^{2tp}]^{r}} =$$

$$\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \frac{rp ^{r-1}}{r(1 - (1 - p)e^{2tp})^{r-1}.(-2te^{2tp} + e^{2tp} + 2tpe^{2tp})} = $$ **undefined**

Whereas applying L’hôpital’s rule inside the exponent yields:

$$\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{p}{1 - (1 - p)e^{2tp}}\right)^{r} = \lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{1 - 2te^{2tp}}\right)^{r} = \left(\frac{1}{1 - 2t}\right)^{r}$$

Which is the correct answer. Can anyone help me understand why the correct answer is the second one and why we’re getting different results?

Comment: Why do you say it's undefined?  It's another indeterminate form. By the way, for the second solution, there's an error: The second term needs to be $\left(\lim\limits_{p\to 0} \dfrac p{1-(1-p)e^{2tp}}\right)^r$. You can't take part of the $p\to 0$ limit without doing it all at once.

Comment: I was not familiar with the term "Indeterminate form". Reading up on that, I can see how the solution comes about when the indeterminate form 0/0 takes on a value of 1. I still don't understand why we can pass L'hopital's rule **through** the parentheses. With regards to the second term, I have not taken part of the limit, I simply applied L'hopital's rule inside the parentheses which took out the p in the numerator, but perhaps I did not fully unserstand your comment.

Comment: Well, the point is that the function $g(x)=x^r$ is continuous (assuming $r\ge 0$), so $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^r = \lim_{x\to a} g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x\to a} f(x))=(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))^r$.

Comment: ...and since the above applies for both the numerator and the denominator, applying L'hopital's rule would yield $\frac{\lim_{p \rightarrow 0}\frac{g(p+\Delta p)-g(p)}{\Delta p}}{\lim_{p \rightarrow 0}\frac{k(p+\Delta p)-k(p)}{\Delta p}}\;$ with the $\Delta p$ cancellation making passing the limit through the exponent possible...am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No, that is not valid. The individual limits may, for example, be $0$, even though the limit of the quotient (as in your case) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @TedShifrin Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Indeterminate forms

> We say that a limit is in an indeterminate form when, by directly calculating known limits and applying the known algebraic properties of limits we cannot reach a conclusion. Take, for instance the following limits:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> &\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{x},\\
> &\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+x}{x},\\
> &\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{x^3}.
> \end{align}$$
>
> All of them are of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, however, the first does not exist, the second is equal to $1$ and the last one is equal to $+\infty$. Thus, we call $\frac{0}{0}$ an indeterminate form.
>
> When we encounter an intdeterminate form we cannot draw any conlcusion, thus we have to take action to lift the indeterminate form - e.g. manipulate the function so as to express it in a form that it is possible to calculate the limit.

As for $\lim\limits_{x\to a}(f(x))^r$, as pointed by @Ted Shifrin, the point in this case is that the function $g(x)=x^r$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$, hence, you can "push" the limit inside $g$.